# Access elements in a JSON object

Tags: python, node.js, arrays, json, aws-lambda

I'm new to JavaScript and AWS. And I invoked a separate Lambda function (Let's say child lambda) from a middle line of the main Lambda function (Let's say parent lambda) and use the returned value from the child lambda in the parent lambda.

My child lambda is implemented in Python 3.6 and parent lambda is implemented in Node.js 12.x.

I have an array assigned to variable 'img'. If a condition satisfies I need to invoke the child lambda by passing the Payload as 'img' array to do some extra calculations on that array and return it back to the parent lambda. And finally replace the 'img' variable with the returned array.

Below is the return code block I used in the child lambda.

```
return { 
    "statusCode": 200, 
        "headers": { 
            "Content-Type": "application/json" 
    }, 
    "body": json.dumps({
        "returnArray": returnArr
    }) 
}
```

returnArr is a 3d array.
I want to access "returnArray" and assign returnArr array to variable 'img'.

Below is the code block I use in the parent lambda to do that (Line 1).

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
AWS.config.region = 'ap-southeast-2';
var lambda = new AWS.Lambda();

exports.handler = async (event, ctx, callback) => {
    //////////code lines for other operations////////////

    let img = //Line A - 3d array;
    let body1;
    if(condition){
        var params = {
                FunctionName: 'childFunction', // child lambda function written in Python 3.6
                InvocationType: 'RequestResponse',
                Payload: JSON.stringify({ "sendImg" : img})
            };
            lambda.invoke(params, function(err, data) {
                if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                } else {
                console.log('Returned '+ data.Payload); //Line B
                let body1;
                if(typeof(data.Payload) == 'object') {
                    body1 = data.Payload;
                } else {
                    body1 = JSON.parse(data.Payload); //
                }
                img = body1.body["returnArray"]; //Line 1
                console.log("arr : "img);  Line 2
                }
            }).promise();
    }
    ////////Rest of the code///////////////////////
};
```

But Line 2 gives this.

```
arr :  undefined
```

I think this is happening since I don't have much NodeJS knowledge.
Could someone kindly tell me How to get the 3d array in Line 1?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You encoded the `body` element, so you need to parse it.

```
img = JSON.parse(body1.body).returnedArray;
```